# GetResponse not working for internal url

Tags: vb.net, httpwebresponse, getresponse

I am trying to return a webpage as a stream.

What i have got so far works when i try and access an external url i.e. 'http://www.google.com'. But when i try and access a website on our server i.e. 'http://servername/applicationname/default.aspx'.

Below is the code that i currently have, that works for external :

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/search?q=google"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
Dim resStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
```

But when i try it with this line i get `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://Server/Application/SubFolder/testing.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)        
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

I have tried altering the credentials it accesses the server with using :

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

And i have tried using a web client :

```
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
Dim myStream As Stream = myWebClient.OpenRead("http://Server/Application/SubFolder/testing.aspx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the 401 error because the web server's authentication is rejecting the request.  You may need to explicitly set your credentials.

```
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "domain")
```